# New outliers appear after I remove existing ones using QQ Plot Results

Tags: r, pca, outliers, mahalanobis

I'm working on the PCA section from Michael Faraway's *Linear Models with R* (chapter 11, page 164).

PCA analysis is sensitive to outliers and the Mahalanobis distance helps us identify them.

The author checks for outliers by plotting the Mahalanobis distance against the quantiles of a chi-squared distribution.

```
if require(faraway)==F install.packages("faraway"); require(faraway)
data(fat, package='faraway')
cfat <- fat[,9:18]

n <- nrow(cfat); p <- ncol(cfat)
plot(qchisq(1:n/(n+1),p), sort(md), xlab=expression(paste(chi^2,
                                                            "quantiles")),
ylab = "Sorted Mahalanobis distances")
abline(0,1)
```

I identify the points:

```
identify(qchisq(1:n/(n+1),p), sort(md))
```

It appears that the outliers are in rows 242:252.  I remove these outliers and re-create the QQ Plot:

```
cfat.mod <- cfat[-c(242:252),]  #remove outliers
robfat <- cov.rob(cfat.mod)
md <- mahalanobis(cfat.mod, center=robfat$center, cov=robfat$cov)
n <- nrow(cfat.mod); p <- ncol(cfat.mod)
plot(qchisq(1:n/(n+1),p), sort(md), xlab=expression(paste(chi^2,
                                                          "quantiles")),
     ylab = "Sorted Mahalanobis distances")
abline(0,1)

identify(qchisq(1:n/(n+1),p), sort(md))
```

Alas, it appears now that a new set of points (rows 234:241) are now outliers.  This keeps happening every time I remove additional outliers.

Look forward to understanding what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: We need `md` to troubleshoot.

Comment: You're probably not doing anything wrong. This is a common problem with models that are misspecified.

Comment: Agree with @Alex, you're recalculating outliers based on the "new" data set that excludes your old outliers.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen "It's outliers all the way down". [Explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down)

Comment: haha, I've never seen that. Good analogy. I like turtles.

Comment: Jenesaisquoi, thank you for the insight.  Hmm, where would I call sort(mod, index.return = T)?  This can't go in the plot function, since using index.returns=T yields a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To identify the points correctly, make sure the labels correspond to the positions of the points in the data.  The functions `order` or `sort` with `index.return=TRUE` will give the sorted indices.  Here is an example, arbitrarily removing the points with `md` greater than a threshold.

```
## Your data
data(fat, package='faraway')
cfat <- fat[, 9:18]
n <- nrow(cfat)
p <- ncol(cfat)
md <- sort(mahalanobis(cfat, colMeans(cfat), cov(cfat)), index.return=TRUE)
xs <- qchisq(1:n/(n+1), p)
plot(xs, md$x, xlab=expression(paste(chi^2, 'quantiles')))

## Use indices in data as labels for interactive identify
identify(xs, md$x, labels=md$ix)

## remove those with md>25, for example
inds <- md$x > 25
cfat.mod <- cfat[-md$ix[inds], ]
nn <- nrow(cfat.mod)
md1 <- mahalanobis(cfat.mod, colMeans(cfat.mod), cov(cfat.mod))

## Plot the new data
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
plot(qchisq(1:nn/(nn+1), p), sort(md1), xlab='chisq quantiles', ylab='')
abline(0, 1, col='red')
car::qqPlot(md1, distribution='chisq', df=p, line='robust', main='With car::qqPlot')
```

[image]